# HTTP POST requests in a foreach loop in angular 6 skipping first item

Tags: angular6, observable, rxjs6

I have a forEach loop which sends http post requests for each item in the loop but for an unknown reason it skips the first item. What could I be doing wrong?
Here is the code:

```
this.shoppingCartProducts.forEach(cartProduct => {
  this.productOrderSrv.addProductToOrder(cartProduct)
            .subscribe((result) => {
              console.log(cartProduct);
            }, error => {
              // error has occured
            });
}
```

The productOrderSrv.addProductToOrder calls the http post request which is a service injected in this component.

I have also tried to implement the forkJoin rxjs method but it also skips the first item (in this case the cartProduct).

Please give me some info on something that I could be doing wrong or missing.

Comment: You can try using a normal for loop first and investigate what is happening.

Comment: let me try and see if it works

Comment: The for loop does not work also It also skips the first item.

Comment: I have tried to debug and step through and it seems the post request is not executing and waiting for completion the first item. It only posts the last item in the loop. What should I implement to wait for the first post request for the first item to finish before proceeding to the next one?

Comment: You can try to implement async await in your service. If you post your service code I can try to help.

Comment: @Abu Zafor. This is my service code.                    
  addProductToOrder(orderProduct: OrderProduct) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'orderproducts/addproducttooreder/', 
                                    orderProduct);
}

Comment: You can try like this one async addProductToOrder(orderProduct: OrderProduct) { return await this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'orderproducts/addproducttooreder/', orderProduct).toPromise();

Comment: @Abu Zafor. And how should I call this method on my component since it is now a promise.

Comment: just normal call. no need to subscribe. like this.productOrderSrv.addProductToOrder(cartProduct);

Comment: @Abu Zafor. I have done that but now it does not go to the next item. It only posts the first item in the forEach loop.

Comment: I have solved the issue by sending all items at one as an array instead of one by one. But I have used the async await as adviced by @Abu Zafor. Thanks.